# Ssh blockedfor foreign vps, ip not blocked

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I live in a high censorship country(iran) and access to my vps was working with some methods but not others. Like ssh tunnel working fine for most of the time.

Recently the ssh server fails to respond but when I connect to a local datacenter ssh works fine and even protocols that didn’t work with my foreign server have no problem connecting to local vps.

I can ping my foreign vps and even used this command it it showed “connected *my domain tied to vps*”

```
telenet *server ipv4* 877 (ssh port)
```

I can connect to my foreign vps through the local vps.

So what type of censorship is being used? At first I thought it was protocol based but now I have evidence it is not protocol based or ip blocking either. It seems to be a combination of both IP and protocol. Any tests I can do to figure out how they are implementing the censorship? It would be great if I can figure out the method while I still have access to my servers. I am using google dns on all devices/ servers

Commercial options mostly fail to connect or connect without giving access to internet. Xvpn connects but they hide the real name of their tunneling protocol so not much to go off

Comment: This is called Deep Packet Inspection, DPI in short which is aware of traffic pattern and thus able to drop desired traffic.

Comment: @ZarehKasparian  oh thanks. I ruled out DPI because I thought traffic pattern didn't take into account the ip I am trying to access. Will try some anti dpi methods and see if it helps.